# Using Struts2 s:set variables with getText()

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

Using Struts2 with JSPs.  The following code works fine:

```
<s:if test="foo == bar">
    <s:set var="keyValue">message.string1</s:set>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:set var="keyValue">message.string2</s:set>
</s:else>

<s:text name="%{keyValue}"/>
```

i.e., based on the value of `keyValue`, `message.string1` or `message.string2` is looked up from the resource file and properly output to the resulting HTML page.

However, as explained at the bottom of the [Struts tag documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/text.html), for i18n in attribute values I can't use the Struts text tag, instead I have to use `getText('...')`:

```
<s:submit value="getText('message.string1')" ../>
```

Problem is, I can't get `%{keyValue}` resolved in the above `getText()` call, whatever syntax I try:  `getText('%{keyValue}')`, `getText(%{keyValue})`, `getText(keyValue)`, `getText('keyValue')` it ends up getting evaluated as null.  Is this a syntax error on my part or it simply can't be done?  If I have to, I know I can go back to using `<s:if>` and `<s:else>` with a submit tag under each:

```
<s:if test="foo == bar">
    <s:submit value="getText('message.string1')" ../>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:submit value="getText('message.string2')" ../>
</s:else>
```

...but I'd like to avoid the duplication if possible.

Comment: Try `<s:submit value="%{getText(keyValue)}" ../>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although plain `keyValue` will work in most cases, it is always better to prefix `var` values of the `<s:set>` tag with `#`.
You should use only one pair of `%{}` around the whole expression.

```
<s:submit value="%{getText(#keyValue)}" />
```

Comment: `Although plain keyValue will work in most cases`, so do you mean there are cases in that it doesn't work?

Comment: @RomanC E.g. here `<s:submit value="%{getText(keyValue)}" />` - won't work.